# Swap image src with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, swap, attr, src

I have one big image and small thumbs, i am trying to swap their src with each other. Here i am changing thumb img in bottleWrapper img, but i want to swap their src. Pls help!

HTML

```
<div class="bottlesWrapper">
  <img src="bottle1.png" />
</div>

<div class="thumbs">
   <img src="bottle2.png" />
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$('.thumbs a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
       var aimg = $(this).find("img")

      $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut('fast',function(){
         $(this).attr('src', $(aimg).attr('src')).fadeIn('fast');
      });

    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks all :)

I actually forgot to give out one information that I have various thumbs, this answer suits best! Thank you all for your precious inputs!

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var thmb = this;
    var src = this.src;
    $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut(400,function(){
        thmb.src = this.src;
        $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    });
});
```

Comment: there is not a tag inside thumbs

Comment: See also this 'Swap gallery' example from Design Chemical:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/ (wouldn't be difficult to add fadein/fadeout I guess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **SWAP** images do like:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/asixuj/4/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var thmb = this;
    var src = this.src;
    $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut(400,function(){
        thmb.src = this.src;
        $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    });
});
```

If you have multiple 'galleries' do like: http://jsbin.com/asixuj/5/edit

Comment: Nopes, this is again changing only BIG img to small image source.. I want that for eg. you have green image on top and when u click on black img thumb, I want black thumb to become pink and display black img at top.. 'Basically want to swap the two images' I hope i dint confuse u

Comment: Hey .. can u explain why [0]?

Comment: @itsMe in jQuery it's like `$(this).attr('src')` in JS it's `this.src` so, to return `$(this)` to native JS element reference (`this`) you use `[0]` so you can do: `$(this)[0].src` instead of `$(this).attr('src')` but I keep `$(this)` instead of using `this` so I can do the jQuery method `.fadeIn(400)`

Answer (score 3):

ther is no `<a>` tag in your question ..so assuming its `img`.. on click of thumbs img.. the `bottlesWrapper` will get swaped..

try this

**updated**

```
 $('.thumbs img').click(function() {
   var img=$(this).attr('src');

  $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut('fast',function(){
     $(this).attr('src', img).fadeIn('fast');
  });

  $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
     var bottlersImg=$('.bottlesWrapper img').attr('src');
     $(this).attr('src', bottlersImg).fadeIn('fast');
  });

});
```

**NOTE**: and you don't need `each` loop ... jquery dose that by using a  class selector works..

Comment: Not working :( Its only changing source of bottlesWrapper img, not of thumbs img

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var img_src = img.attr('src');

    $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
      $(this).attr('src', $('.bottlesWrapper img').attr('src')).fadeIn('fast');
    });

    $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut('fast',function(){
       $(this).attr('src', img_src ).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

You should attach click events to `img` tags inside `thumbs` class and then change the image source.

Comment: Nopes, it dint work :( Its only changing source of bottlesWrapper img, not thumbs img

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have a `<a>` tag in the `.thumb` your code won't work at all, instead try clicking the `.thumb` itself:

```
$('.thumbs').click(function() {
    var thumbsimgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
    var bottleImgSrc = $('.bottlesWrapper img').attr('src');

    $(this).find("img").attr('src', bottleImgSrc);

    $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut('fast').promise().done(function(){
       $(this).attr('src', thumbsimgSrc).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  });
});
```

And `.thumb` is itself is a collection so you don't need to iterate through `.each()` method.

Comment: @itsMe Thanks you had a look at this one.